# ping computers and list logged in user

Tags: powershell, shell

i got a question to my existing script.
the script does exactly what it should to do
This is what i got.

```
<#
Ping mass huge amount of hosts in parallel multithreading
#>
function Parallel-Ping {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string[]]$hosts,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][int]$timeout = 2000,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][ValidateRange(1,255)][int]$ttl = 128,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][bool]$DontFragment = $false,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][byte[]]$data = ([byte[]]0),
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][int]$MaxConcurrent = [System.Environment]::ProcessorCount,
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][switch]$showprogress
)
begin{
    $rspool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,$MaxConcurrent)
    $rspool.ApartmentState = 'STA'
    $rspool.Open()
    $jobs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
}
process{
    foreach ($hostname in $hosts){
        $ps = [Powershell]::Create()
        $ps.RunspacePool = $rspool
        [void]$ps.AddScript({
            param($hostname,$timeout,$ttl,$DontFragment,$data)
            $result = [ordered]@{Host=$hostname;Address=$null;Status=[System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus]::Unknown;RoundtripTime = -1;TTL=$ttl;DontFragment=$DontFragment;ResponseBuffer='';Time=(get-date)}
            $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
            try{
                $reply = $ping.Send($hostname,$timeout,$data,(New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions($ttl,$DontFragment)))
                $result.RoundtripTime = $reply.RoundtripTime
                $result.Status = $reply.Status
                $result.Address = $reply.Address
                $result.ResponseBuffer = $reply.Buffer
            }catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException] {
                $result.Status = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus]::DestinationHostUnreachable
            }finally{
                $ping.Dispose()
            }
            [pscustomobject]$result
        }).AddParameters(@($hostname,$timeout,$ttl,$DontFragment,$data))
        $job = $ps.BeginInvoke()
        [void]$jobs.Add(([pscustomobject]@{Handle = $job; Powershell = $ps}))
    }
}
end{
    write-verbose "Waiting for all jobs to complete."
    while(($jobs | ?{!$_.Handle.IsCompleted})){
        if ($showprogress.IsPresent){
            $completed = ($jobs | ?{$_.Handle.IsCompleted}).Count
            Write-Progress -Activity $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName -Status "Pinging a total of $($hosts.Count) hosts." -PercentComplete (($completed / $hosts.Count) * 100) -CurrentOperation "Completed $completed from $($hosts.Count)."
        }
    }
    # get results of jobs
    $results = $jobs | %{
        $_.Powershell.EndInvoke($_.handle)
        $_.Powershell.Dispose()
    }
    # cleanup
    $rspool.Close();$rspool.Dispose()
    $results
}
}
$hosts = Get-Content 'E:\ips.txt'
Parallel-Ping -hosts $hosts -timeout 500 -MaxConcurrent 50 -showprogress | ogv
```

I would like to mention another function in my script.
My goal is it, to add the function that i can see the actual logged in user to the pinged machines?
Unfortunately i dont know where to add.

Comment: I guess you can add this to the `try` block: `$result['LoggedOnUser'] = (Get-CimInstance –ComputerName $hostname –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`

Comment: your code never actually connects to anything beyond getting a ping response. so there is no info beyond that available. have you taken a look at using `Invoke-Command` to run a scriptblock on the target systems? it can show you the non-responders ...

Comment: @Theo which line do you mean?

Comment: Like I said, put an extra line in the try block to add another property to the `$result` Hashtable. That was before I read the code completely, so I would recommend focussing on what @Lee_Dailey commented first.